# How to set the DOCTYPE of an XMLDocument in Swift

Tags: swift, xml

I can't figure out how to set the `<!DOCTYPE ...` value of an [XMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmldocument) in Swift. I created the `XMLDocument` that I want, I just need to set the `!DOCTYPE` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `XMLDTD` class.

Here's a simple example:

```
var root = XMLElement(name: "hello", stringValue: "there")
var xml = XMLDocument(rootElement: root)
var dtd = XMLDTD()
dtd.name = "node"
dtd.publicID = "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
dtd.systemID = "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd"
xml.dtd = dtd
print(xml)
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<hello>there</hello>
```

Comment: That is very close to what I am looking for. I'm actually trying to synthesize the DBus introspection data format defined [here](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#introspection-format).
How do I get `<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC...`?

Comment: Please update your question with a clear example of the results you need.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to know how to set the name, but I'm not an XML expert and Apple doesn't make it easy with their docs. Thank you for the help!